# Programically convert a fixed width .dat file with a .fmt file into a .csv file using Python or Python/Pandas

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to learn Python but I'm stuck here, any help appreciated.

I have 2 files.

1 is a .dat file with no column headers that is fixed width containing multiple rows of data
1 is a .fmt file that contains the column headers, column length, and datatype

.dat example:

```
10IFKDHGHS34
12IFKDHGHH35
53IFHDHGDF33
```

.fmt example:

```
ID,2,n
NAME,8,c
CODE,2,n
```

Desired Output as .csv:

```
ID,NAME,CODE
10,IFKDHGHS,34
12,IFKDHGHH,35
53,IFHDHGDF,33
```

Comment: Should the third column of the fmt file affect the csv output?

Comment: I believe the third column specifies the datatype.

Comment: Jwilner is correct, the 3rd column of fmt does not affect csv output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd parse the format file.

```
with open("format_file.fmt") as f:
    # csv.reader parses away the commas for us 
    # and we get rows as nice lists
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    # this will give us a list of lists that looks like
    # [["ID", "2", "n"], ...]
    row_definitions = list(reader)

# iterate and just unpack the headers
# this gives us ["ID", "NAME", "CODE"]
header = [name for name, length, dtype in row_definitions]
# [2, 8, 2]
lengths = [int(length) for name, length, dtype in row_definitions]

# define a generator (possibly as a closure) that simply slices 
# into the string bit by bit -- this yields, for example, first 
# characters 0 - 2, then characters 2 - 10, then 8 - 12
def parse_line(line):
    start = 0
    for length in lengths:
        yield line[start: start+length]
        start = start + length

with open(data_file) as f:
     # iterating over a file pointer gives us each line separately
     # we call list on each use of parse_line to force the generator to a list
     parsed_lines = [list(parse_line(line)) for line in data_file]

# prepend the header
table = [header] + parsed_lines

# use the csv module again to easily output to csv
with open("my_output_file.csv", 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(table)
```

Comment: I've hacked around with this. I'm able to get the column headers to work but it splits the characters down the page for the data file. Not able to get it to work.